# warning: libcryptopp.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement

Tags: android, android-ndk, crypto++

I am trying to build `libcryptopp.so` and include it in my JNI code, follow the guide in [Android Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)), I experienced the following problems.

**Missing symbol problems in Crypto++ 5.6.3**

Originally I used Crypto++ 5.6.3, I came across this problem:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Z9GlobalRNGv" 

referenced by "/data/app/com.example.administrator.jnitest-2/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so"...
```

I check the `libcryptopp.so`:

```
$ readelf -Ws libcryptopp.so | grep _Z9GlobalRNGv
1406: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Z9GlobalRNGv
15836: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Z9GlobalRNGv
```

switching to Crypto++ 5.6.4 fix this problem, but I still do not know the cause and met another problem:

**Missing DT_SONAME**

```
12-21 09:50:20.837 21677-21677/com.example.administrator.jnitest   
W/linker: /data/app/com.example.administrator.jnitest- 1/lib/arm/libcryptopp.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a 
replacement: "libcryptopp.so"
```

Actually this is only a **warning**, app will not crash.

I am using the latest version of android Mashwallow MOB31K.
Somebody have also experienced similar problems using other libraries

```
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/188
```

on Android N-preview.

Why am I getting the warning, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is a great intention to share your knowledge :) Although, the right way to do this is to post a question, as if you were actually having a problem, and answering your own question. If you let your post as it is now, people will never know you actually give an answer. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @Yao - 5.6.3 added SONAME. We noticed people were having problems with versioned libs on iOS and Android, so we removed SONAME for mobile targets at 5.6.4. There's a few questions on the mailing list about Android and versioned libs. Also see [Commit d9c3c51aa8d3e710, Make non-SOLIBNAME the default version for Android and Embedded](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/d9c3c51aa8d3e710b296b640d768d7b2cbac6efc).

Comment: @Rightleg, thank you for instruction, I am a new guy.  I am sorry that I later find it is actually a warning, I have made the correction. But hopefully this may still be useful.

Comment: @jww  thank you for your answer,  currently maybe the best solution is leaving alone this warning.

Comment: @yao - I don't recall seeing the *"libcryptopp.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename..."* warning. I also don't recall if I have tested under Mashwallow  either. I'll keep an eye out for the warning. Maybe we should add a message that tells someone how to enable the versioned lib if they want it.

Comment: @yao - Crypto++ 5.7 will have a message telling folks how to create a versioned shared object if they want one. Also see [Commit 182f87eeacea3d65](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/182f87eeacea3d6571100bf7e486177798a5c1d9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some attempts, I  find one **imperfect** solution.

It appears that android N turns requires library version now.

turn on **SONAME** flag on build.

Cryptopp turns off the version flag by defaults. In the GNUmakefile-cross,:

```
HAS_SOLIB_VERSION ?= 0
```

set the value to 1:

```
HAS_SOLIB_VERSION ?= 1
```

build, and then use the generated .so file. the warning will go.

**the problem is that is library will not work on android 5.0. So we'd better leave alone this warning now.**